# Why my email goes up to the page before my paper starts?

Tags: pdftex, email

Why my email goes up to the page before my paper starts?

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{url}

\renewcommand{\Gamma}{\varGamma}
\renewcommand{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}
\renewcommand{\bar}{\overline}
\renewcommand{\hat}{\widehat}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Cir}{Cir}

\renewcommand{\leq}{\leqslant}
\renewcommand{\geq}{\geqslant}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}[lemma]{Remark}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

%Extra things that are included for simplicity.

\newcommand{\Po}{\mathcal{P}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
%
%
\newcommand{\Sym}{\mathrm{Sym}}
\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}%
\newcommand{\vt}{\mathrm{vert}}
\newcommand{\conv}{\mathrm{conv}}
\newcommand{\Fix}{\mathrm{Fix}}
\newcommand{\Span}{\mathrm{Span}}
\newcommand{\core}{\mathrm{core}}
\newcommand{\PCir }{\mathrm{PCir }}
% Used for displaying a sample figure. If possible, figure files should
% be included in EPS format.
%
% If you use the hyperref package, please uncomment the following line
% to display URLs in blue roman font according to Springer's eBook style:
% \renewcommand\UrlFont{\color{blue}\rmfamily}

\begin{document}
%
\title{Outer approximations of core points for integer programming\thanks{Supported by NSERC grant RGPIN-2015-04955}}
%
%\titlerunning{Outer approximations of core points}
% If the paper title is too long for the running head, you can set
% an abbreviated paper title here
%
\author{Naghmeh Shahverdi\and
David Bremner}

%
%\authorrunning{ David Bremner and Naghmeh Shahverdi }
% First names are abbreviated in the running head.
% If there are more than two authors, 'et al.' is used.
%
%\institute{University of New Brunswick, Fredericton, NB, E3B 5A3 , Canada \\

\email{\{ nshahver,bremner \}@unb.ca}}
%
\maketitle              % typeset the header of the contribution
%
```

[image]

Comment: I can't compile this example because I get "undefined control sequence" for \email{} but my guess would be that you have your \maketitle information inside the document and not in the preamble. Usually the \maketitle is the very first thing you put in after \begin{document} and all the information it pulls is in the preamble. Or at least, that's how I have always done it.

Comment: it changes the format of title if I put makefile in the begining

Comment: Please tell us how or where `\email` is defined.

Comment: `\maketitle` typesets the `\title`, `\author` and `\date`, all as one unit. You have `\email` *before* `\maketitle`, so that is where it goes, before. Do `xxx\maketitle yyy` to make visible where the title box starts and ends.

Comment: Some document classes define \email to be included in the \maketitle.  Article class does not.